# Strange makefile build error

Tags: c, struct

I'm working on this very simple part of code, but somehow the build error is pretty strange to me.
I have these files in the project: `main.c`, `http_request.h`, `http_request.c`; and a simple `Makefile`.

**1. http_request.h**

```
/* STRUCTURES */
struct http_param {
    char    key[MAX_BUFFER];
    char    *value;
};

struct http_request {
    int     size;
    struct  http_param  data[MAX_PARAM];
};

/* FUNCTIONS */
int parse_http_request(apr_pool_t *pool, const char *args, struct http_request *req); /* (A) */
```

**2. http_request.c**

```
#include <http_request.h>
...// something else goes here, it's fine

int 
parse_http_request(apr_pool_t *pool, const char *args, struct http_request *req) /* (B) */
{
```

**3. Makefile**

```
-I$(PROJECT_DIR)/include
```

this directory contains `http_request.h`.

Then I build, it raises this error:

```
/project/src/http_request.c:14: warning: 'struct http_request' declared inside parameter list
/project/src/http_request.c:14: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
/project/src/http_request.c: In function 'parse_http_request':
```

The error points to `(A)` and `(B)` as I mentioned in source code above.

Could anyone help to find out what the problem is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, seeing that you use apr_pool_t, that you also have apache includes in your include path. apache also provides a file called http_request.h and that one gets included instead of the one you have.

Comment: Oh, c'mon...my really bad. I would've never known that my `http_request.h` conflicts with the one in Apache module provider also. I've fixed and it's just running cool now. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @xjaphx One more experience learned, next time you'll recognize it. :) Just wait for the debugging joy when a project you work on creates util.h and/or config.h.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#include "http_request.h"
```

instead of

```
#include <http_request.h>
```